# Como faço para usar fgets no lugar do gets?

Tags: c, string, buffer

antes de "falar" do meu problema, olhe primeiro o meu código e ignore os erros de acentuação no console se for executar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main(){
  char nome[41];
  printf("Texto: ");
  fgets(nome, 40, stdin);
  if (strcmp(nome, "0") == 0) {
    printf("Sim. fgets está funcionando.\n");
  } else {
    printf("Não. fgets não está funcionado.\n");
  }
  printf("Texto: ");
  gets(nome);
  if (strcmp(nome, "0") == 0){
    printf("Sim. gets está funcionando.\n");
  } else {
    printf("Não. gets não está funcionando.\n");
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando digito "0" pelo comando **fgets**, o IF não encontra o "0", MAS quando digito "0" pelo **gets** o IF encontra o "0".

Eu quero evitar o **gets**, pois muito sites/livros recomendar não usar esse comando, pois o mesmo é perigoso e dá erro de buffer. (até agora, eu não tive problemas relacionado a buffer)
mas infezlimente o **fgets** não está funcionado como eu queria, só o **gets** está funcionando nos meus códigos, mas quero evitar.

Alguém sabe fazer o **fgets** ter o caracteres ser detectado pelo o IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função fgets coloca '\n' na final da string lida. Assim, neste seu caso, o conteúdo de "nome" vai ser "0\n", e não apenas "0".

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda, graças a você os mesmo códigos vão ficar melhores e valeu pelo site que portou.